# このコードの量を減らしたい！

Tags: javascript

JavaScriptのチャイムを実装したいです。
コード量が多いので、コードの量を減らしたいと思いました。

```
//setInterval(String,mmS) 1000mms = 1s
setInterval(clock, 1000); //1秒ごとに結果を反映

function clock() {
  var weeks = new Array("Sun", "Mon", "Thu", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri", "Sat");
  //曜日を出力
  var now = new Date();
  var y = now.getFullYear();
  var mo = now.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = now.getDate();
  var w = weeks[now.getDay()];
  var h = now.getHours();
  var mi = now.getMinutes();
  var s = now.getSeconds();

  if (mo < 10) {
    mo = "0" + mo
  };
  if (d < 10) {
    d = "0" + d;
  }
  if (mi < 10) {
    mi = "0" + mi;
  }
  if (s < 10) {
    s = "0" + s;
  }

  var date = y + "/" + mo + "/" + d + " (" + w + ")";
  var time = h + ":" + mi + ":" + s;

  document.getElementById("clock_date").innerHTML = y + "/" + mo + "/" + d + " (" + w + ")";
  document.getElementById("clock_time").innerHTML = h + ":" + mi + ":" + s;
  //document.getElementById("clock_date").innerHTML = date;
  //document.getElementById("clock_time").innerHTML = time;
  document.getElementById("clock_frame").style.fontSize = window.innerWidth / 10 + "px";

  //var get_time = document.getElementById('clock_time'); // HTML要素オブジェクトを取得
  // console.log(get_time); //[object HTMLParagraphElement]  要素全てをログ出力？
  var get_date = document.getElementById('clock_date').innerHTML;
  console.log(get_date); //日数のみ出力

  var get_time = document.getElementById('clock_time').innerHTML;
  console.log(get_time); //時間のみ出力

  console.log(w);

  if (w === "Sun" || w === "Sat") { // もし土曜日もしくは日曜日でないなら
    console.log("休日");

    // チャイムを作動させない
  } else {
    console.log("平日");

    switch (time) {
    case "09:30:00": //0限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("0限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "09:45:00": //0限END・1限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("1限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "10:35:00": //1限END・休み時間START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("1限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "10:45:00": //休み時間END・2限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("2限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "11:35:00": //2限END・休み時間START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("2限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "11:45:00": //休み時間END・3限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("3限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "12:35:00": //3限END・昼休みSTART
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("3限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "13:15:00": //昼休みEND・4限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("4限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "14:05:00": //4限END・休み時間START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("4限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "14:15:00": //休み時間END・5限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("5限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "15:05:00": //5限END・休み時間START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("5限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "15:15:00": //休み時間END・6限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("6限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "16:05:00": //6限END・終礼など
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("6限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "16:15:00": //休み時間END・7限START
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("7限目が始まりました。");
      break;

    case "17:05:00": //7限END
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("7限目が終わりました。");
      break;

    case "17:50:00": //下校の促し    
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("下校する時間の10分前になりました。");
      break;

    case "18:00:00": //完全下校
      document.getElementById("Sound").play();
      alert("下校する時間になりました。");
      //音楽を再生する
      break;

    default:
      break;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 「スマートにしたい」だと何がスマートの判定かが主観的になりがちなので、もうちょっと具体的に、コード量を半分にしたいとか、ステップ数を半分にしたいとか具体的に書き直してください。

Comment: 単純にコード量が少なければ良いというものでもないと思いますが、ケース文の判定部分で時間が埋め込みになっているので保守性が下がる＆冗長に感じる箇所なのかなと思います。

Comment: パッと見た感じですと、連想配列を使えば、switch文を省略できそうな気がしますね。

Answer (score 8):

JavaScriptオブジェクト（連想配列）を使って、

```
const data = {
    "09:30:00":{lesson: 0, message: "始まり"},
    "09:45:00":{lesson: 1, message: "始まり"},
    "10:35:00":{lesson: 1, message: "終わり"},
    "10:45:00":{lesson: 2, message: "始まり"},
    "11:35:00":{lesson: 2, message: "終わり"},
    "11:45:00":{lesson: 3, message: "始まり"},
    "12:35:00":{lesson: 3, message: "終わり"},
    "13:15:00":{lesson: 4, message: "始まり"},
    "14:05:00":{lesson: 4, message: "終わり"},
    "14:15:00":{lesson: 5, message: "始まり"},
    "15:05:00":{lesson: 5, message: "終わり"},
    "15:15:00":{lesson: 6, message: "始まり"},
    "16:05:00":{lesson: 6, message: "終わり"},
    "16:15:00":{lesson: 7, message: "始まり"},
    "17:05:00":{lesson: 7, message: "終わり"},
    "17:50:00":{lesson: 8, message: "下校する時間の10分前になりました。"},
    "18:00:00":{lesson: 9, message: "下校する時間になりました。"}
};
```

としておいて、`switch (time)`以下を次のようにするとかなりすっきりします。

```
if (time in data) {
    document.getElementById("Sound").play();
    if (data[time].lesson < 8)
        alert(`${data[time].lesson}時限目が${data[time].message}ました。`);
    else {
        alert(data[time].message);
        if (data[time].lesson === 9) {
            //音楽を再生する
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: なるほど…ありがとうございます。
かなりスマートになりました！